# I want to use HTTPS connection on my GIT repo and the crendentials are in data bags

Tags: github, chef-infra

I am trying to create a recipe that will download my git repo using my user name and password which are inside a databag. This is my code and beneath is an error that says it can't get my credentials in my git block. Any ideas?

```
accounts = data_bag_item('databag_name', 'databag_item')

git "my_repo" do
  user accounts
  puts user.inspect
  repository "https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git"
  reference "branch"
  destination "/var/www/myrepo"
  action :sync
end
```

My error was :

```
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:172:in `getpwnam': can't find user for accounts (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:172:in `uid'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:92:in `set_user'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:226:in `block in fork_subprocess'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:222:in `fork'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:222:in `fork_subprocess'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:35:in `run_command'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:222:in `run_command'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:30:in `shell_out'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:35:in `shell_out!'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:222:in `remote_resolve_reference'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:212:in `target_revision'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in define_resource_requirements'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:232:in `call'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:232:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:322:in `block in run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:321:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:321:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:128:in `process_resource_requirements'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:105:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:597:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:378:in `converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:420:in `do_run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application.rb:140:in `run_chef_client'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:274:in `block in run_application'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:267:in `loop'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:267:in `run_application'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application.rb:72:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
---- End output of git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch ----
Ran git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/themes/recipes/default.rb

 34: git "my_repo" do
 35:   user "accounts"
 36:   puts user.inspect
 37:   repository "https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git"
 38:   reference "branch"
 39:   destination "/var/www/my_repo"
 41:   action :sync
 42: end
 43: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/themes/recipes/default.rb:34:in `from_file'

git("my_repo") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Git
  action [:sync]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  destination "/var/www/my_repo"
  revision "branch"
  remote "origin"
  cookbook_name "themes"
  recipe_name "default"
  user "accounts"
  repository "https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git"
end

[2013-01-31T10:12:21+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-01-31T10:12:21+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-01-31T10:12:21+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-01-31T10:12:21+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-01-31T10:12:21+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: git[my_repo] (themes::default line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:172:in `getpwnam': can't find user for accounts (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:172:in `uid'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:92:in `set_user'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:226:in `block in fork_subprocess'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:222:in `fork'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:222:in `fork_subprocess'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:35:in `run_command'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.1.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:222:in `run_command'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:30:in `shell_out'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:35:in `shell_out!'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:222:in `remote_resolve_reference'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:212:in `target_revision'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider/git.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in define_resource_requirements'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:232:in `call'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:232:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:322:in `block in run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:321:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:321:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:128:in `process_resource_requirements'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:105:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:597:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:378:in `converge'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:420:in `do_run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application.rb:140:in `run_chef_client'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:274:in `block in run_application'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:267:in `loop'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application/client.rb:267:in `run_application'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/lib/chef/application.rb:72:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.18.2/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
---- End output of git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch ----
Ran git ls-remote https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git branch returned 1

---
```

Is there a sample code that shows how I can download my code from github with authentication via databags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `user` attribute in the **git** resource is not the username on GitHub, but a system user that will be the owner of the directory where you clone the repository. Obviously you don't have the system user *accounts* created, so that's why you get the error.

Your git resource should look like this:

```
git "/var/www/myrepo" do
  repository "git@github.com:username/myrepo.git" #or "https://github.com/my_repo/myrepo.git"
  revision "HEAD"
  action :sync
end
```

But you need some mechanism to authenticate on GitHub. I propose using ssh-keys, because I don't know any way to store your password for authentication for good - only some [caching](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) for small amount of time is available. You can generate a key pair according to [this guide on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). You can then save your private key in an **encrypted data bag**.

```
{
  "id": "mykeys",
  "private": "[The private key with newlines replaced with \n]",
  "public": "[The public key with newlines replaced with \n]"
}
```

Then you can use your data bag in the recipe to recreate a private key file in ~/.ssh/id_rsa

```
keys = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('databag_name', 'mykeys')

directory ::File.join( ENV['HOME'], '.ssh' ) do
  mode 0755
end

file ::File.join( ENV['HOME'], '.ssh', 'id_rsa' ) do
  content keys['private']
  mode 0600
end
```

To skip checking authenticity of host 'github.com' create a file in your cookbook *files/default/config* with the following contents.

```
Host github.com
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

And add the folowing to the recipe:

```
cookbook_file ::File.join( ENV['HOME'], '.ssh', 'config' ) do
  mode 0644
end
```

If you want to clone the repository not as *root*, but as some other user then you have to create all the *.ssh* configuration files in that user's home directory.

Comment: Is this still the preferred method for cloning a private git repo?